# javascript memory management of let vs var vs const

Tags: javascript

Is there any difference between javascript's `let`, `var`, and `const` in terms of memory management and performance?

Keeping aside the major difference that `const` variables can't be reassigned a value, does using `const` actually save memory compared to `let` or `var` (such as javascript would assign exactly the needed amount of memory to store the value?)

Comment: They do slightly different things so they get compiled and optimised slightly differently, but these differences are so small that they should not affect your decision when to use which.

Comment: I'm building a really large-scale project, and processing a lot of data... So I'm looking for ways to optimize the code when this is possible.

Comment: This is not a way. Choose the declaration (`let` or `const`) to benefit the code readability for developers, in large-scale projects improved maintainability is a much larger optimisation factor than twiddling with memory.

Comment: Also, the rule of thumb for optimising javascript performance is to write idiomatic code - as that is what engines aim for to optimise best.